# Using PDFBox v2 remove some unwanted text from PDF files

Tags: java, string, pdf, hyperlink, pdfbox

I'm trying to clean a some of PDF documents from hyperlinks and unwanted, not original text

I'm using this function, to clean all hyperlinks and some unwanted text from PDF

```
private int processText(PDPage page) throws IOException {
        int counter = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        List<Object> filteredTokens = new ArrayList<>();

        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
        Object token = parser.parseNextToken();
        while (token != null) {
            boolean filtered = true;
            if (token instanceof Operator) {
                String name = ((Operator) token).getName();
                if ("Tj".equals(name)) {
                    COSString stringToken = (COSString) filteredTokens.get(filteredTokens.size() - 1);

                    if (stringToken.getString().contains("http://") || stringToken.getString().contains("https://") || stringToken.getString().contains("Dr-Bios.com")
                            || stringToken.getString().contains("www.kythuatvitinh.com")) {
                        print(stringToken.getString());
                        filteredTokens.remove(filteredTokens.size() - 1);
                        filtered = false;
                        found = true;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (filtered)
                filteredTokens.add(token);
            token = parser.parseNextToken();
        }

        if (found) {
            PDStream newContents = new PDStream(_document);
            try (OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream()) {
                ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
                writer.writeTokens(filteredTokens);
            }
            page.setContents(newContents);
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

This function works great with hyperlinks, but it doesn't find texts like, "Dr-Bios.com", I think they using some tricks. Can help me someone figure it out? They are adding the same text on all pages (Just text, not hyperlinks).

Image with example bellow:

[image: pdf file example]

PDF file example here: [ACER 4253 ZQE ZQG.pdf](https://easyupload.io/q0dv0f)

Comment: remove "/FXX0 Do" from the page content stream. Look at the file with PDFDebugger.

Comment: The call of that form XObject even is tagged as Watermark Pagination Artifact. You might want to remove all marked content sections marked like that.